"Verte" do not match in conjugation tables
I didn't know Spanish at all, and I tried to read Rosales' poems based on translations. In his poem Verte, qué visión tan, I can't find "verte" in the conjugation tables.
I'm guessing verte is a conjugation of ver. But I haven't been able to verify it in the dictionary. Is the word some kind of colloquial expression? Hope someone can help me answer this question.

I think the crucial thing you need to know is that pronouns (in this case te) can be attached to the end of a verb form. The complete rules for this are too long to put in a comment.

The verb is ver, te is a pronoun.

Verte no es una conjugación del verbo ver.
Es la base verbal, en este caso ver seguido de un pronombre enclítico: te, que es la segunda persona del singular (you).
Algunos ejemplos:

Hablarme: talk to me
Corregirlos: correct them
Verte: To see you

Estos se forman con los pronombres átonos:

me
te, se
le, lo, la
nos
os
los, las

La variedad se debe a los rasgos de género, número y persona.
La gramática tiene un capítulo sobre la Sintaxis de los pronombres átonos. Pronombres proclíticos y enclíticos

Los pronombres átonos dependen morfofonológicamente de un verbo. Cuando aparecen como enclíticos, siguen a la base verbal a la que se adjuntan y forman con ella una sola palabra gráfica: leerlo, dándosela.

Recomiendo la lectura del artículo, pues describe a detalle las reglas a seguir.
Lo básico es que estos pronombres:

Forman una sola palabra con el verbo al que se adjuntan.
Estas palabras se acentúan de acuerdo a las reglas generales de acentuación.
Se pueden usar con verbos en

infinitivo (decirlo, decirme, decirnos)
gerundio: (diciéndolo, diciéndole, diciéndonos)
imperativo: (dilo , dime, dinos)



Finalmente, para responder a tu pregunta, no es una forma de expresión coloquial. Esto se usa a lo largo y ancho del idioma en todo tipo de expresiones.
